# Calculate Median for a group based on lag and lead values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a complex ask, hence would appreciate your patience.

For each datapoint, I would like to first capture the values from lag and lead columns, and then identify those values in the series for my dataset, and compute the median value using the captured values for each group.

[image]

```
Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag,lead
Group1,42005,1,2503,0,2
Group1,42036,2,3734,0,2
Group1,42064,3,6631,2,3
Group1,42095,4,8606,0,0
Group1,42125,5,1889,0,2
Group1,42156,6,4819,1,2
Group1,42186,7,3294,1,0
Group1,42217,8,38999,2,0
Group1,42248,9,28372,1,0
Group1,42278,10,25396,4,1
Group1,42309,11,21093,1,0
Group2,42339,1,9263,0,3
Group2,42005,2,6660,1,3
Group2,42036,3,28595,2,2
Group2,42064,4,123,2,0
Group2,42095,5,11855,3,3
Group2,42125,6,15845,4,3
Group2,42156,7,32331,2,2
Group2,42186,8,3188,1,1
Group2,42217,9,38161,4,0
```

For example, if we look at Month 6 for Group1, the Sales value is 4819, the lag and lead value is 1, and 2 respectively.
I would like to first capture the lag and lead values, and then vlookup in the series. For 4819, for lag(value=1), i would like to go till one datapoint above 4819, (which is 1889, a.k.a 4819->1889, similarly for lead(value=2), i would like to go till two datapoints below 4891, which are 3294 and 38999. So now capture points for 4819 datapoint, is 1899,4819,3294 and 38999, hence now i would like to take the median of this, and store it in my output. THis exercise i want to do for each group.

Similarly, for Group 2, Month 4, i would like to take capture previous 2 lag datapoints with reference to 123( lead is zero, hence it will not be captured), and take median of the the total 3 values.

I tried the same for one particular case with an ifelse condition, to see how it works.

**df$output <- ifelse(lag==0 & lead==1, median(Sales,lead(Sales,1)),0)**

The result was very surprising. R took the median of all the values for the column. Another problem is even if it had worked, i would have to write multiple ifelse conditions, hence looking for a simpler solution.

Not sure how to do the approach the problem and do the exercise for each group in R.

Below is the output i am trying to achieve.

```
Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag,lead,Output
Group1,42005,1,2503,0,2,3734
Group1,42036,2,3734,0,2,6631
Group1,42064,3,6631,2,3,4276.5
Group1,42095,4,8606,0,0,8606
Group1,42125,5,1889,0,2,3294
Group1,42156,6,4819,1,2,4056.5
Group1,42186,7,3294,1,0,4056.5
Group1,42217,8,38999,2,0,4819
Group1,42248,9,28372,1,0,33685.5
Group1,42278,10,25396,4,1,23244.5
Group1,42309,11,21093,1,0,23244.5
Group2,42339,1,9263,0,3,7961.5
Group2,42005,2,6660,1,3,9263
Group2,42036,3,28595,2,2,9263
Group2,42064,4,123,2,0,6660
Group2,42095,5,11855,3,3,11855
Group2,42125,6,15845,4,3,13850
Group2,42156,7,32331,2,2,15845
Group2,42186,8,3188,1,1,32331
Group2,42217,9,38161,4,0,15845
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

I am missing something. please guide me how to solve this problem. If there is any function that i needs to use, please help me with the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
df$Output <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), # For each row (number) in df
                    function(i) 
                      # take the median of Sales from
                      # current row - current lag value
                      # to
                      # current row + current lead value
                      with(df, median(Sales[(i - lag[i]):(i + lead[i])])))
```

Data Used:

```
df <- data.table::fread("
Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag,lead
Group1,42005,1,2503,0,2
Group1,42036,2,3734,0,2
Group1,42064,3,6631,2,3
Group1,42095,4,8606,0,0
Group1,42125,5,1889,0,2
Group1,42156,6,4819,1,2
Group1,42186,7,3294,1,0
Group1,42217,8,38999,2,0
Group1,42248,9,28372,1,0
Group1,42278,10,25396,4,1
Group1,42309,11,21093,1,0
Group2,42339,1,9263,0,3
Group2,42005,2,6660,1,3
Group2,42036,3,28595,2,2
Group2,42064,4,123,2,0
Group2,42095,5,11855,3,3
Group2,42125,6,15845,4,3
Group2,42156,7,32331,2,2
Group2,42186,8,3188,1,1
Group2,42217,9,38161,4,0
")


dout <- fread("
Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag,lead,Output
Group1,42005,1,2503,0,2,3734
Group1,42036,2,3734,0,2,6631
Group1,42064,3,6631,2,3,4276.5
Group1,42095,4,8606,0,0,8606
Group1,42125,5,1889,0,2,3294
Group1,42156,6,4819,1,2,4056.5
Group1,42186,7,3294,1,0,4056.5
Group1,42217,8,38999,2,0,4819
Group1,42248,9,28372,1,0,33685.5
Group1,42278,10,25396,4,1,23244.5
Group1,42309,11,21093,1,0,23244.5
Group2,42339,1,9263,0,3,7961.5
Group2,42005,2,6660,1,3,9263
Group2,42036,3,28595,2,2,9263
Group2,42064,4,123,2,0,6660
Group2,42095,5,11855,3,3,11855
Group2,42125,6,15845,4,3,13850
Group2,42156,7,32331,2,2,15845
Group2,42186,8,3188,1,1,32331
Group2,42217,9,38161,4,0,15845
")
all.equal(df$Output, dout$Output)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setDT(df)[,i:=sequence(.N)][,med:=as.numeric(median(df$Sales[c((i-lag):(i+lead))])),by=i][,i:=NULL][]
     Group  Date Month Sales lag lead     med
 1: Group1 42005     1  2503   0    2  3734.0
 2: Group1 42036     2  3734   0    2  6631.0
 3: Group1 42064     3  6631   2    3  4276.5
 4: Group1 42095     4  8606   0    0  8606.0
 5: Group1 42125     5  1889   0    2  3294.0
 6: Group1 42156     6  4819   1    2  4056.5
 7: Group1 42186     7  3294   1    0  4056.5
 8: Group1 42217     8 38999   2    0  4819.0
 9: Group1 42248     9 28372   1    0 33685.5
10: Group1 42278    10 25396   4    1 23244.5
11: Group1 42309    11 21093   1    0 23244.5
12: Group2 42339     1  9263   0    3  7961.5
13: Group2 42005     2  6660   1    3  9263.0
14: Group2 42036     3 28595   2    2  9263.0
15: Group2 42064     4   123   2    0  6660.0
16: Group2 42095     5 11855   3    3 11855.0
17: Group2 42125     6 15845   4    3 13850.0
18: Group2 42156     7 32331   2    2 15845.0
19: Group2 42186     8  3188   1    1 32331.0
20: Group2 42217     9 38161   4    0 15845.0
```